# Blue screen and all programs not working after booting up from chrome os

Tags: 16.04, boot, error-handling

(sorry, it won't let me post pictures)

Hello, today when I went on to my Chromebook and tried to load up Ubuntu, it took 3 minutes to load and then I was stuck on a blue screen, of which I could not do anything, open any programs, or run the terminal. My cursor was replaced with an 'X' and could right click, only to find it was useless for I couldn't do anything. This is the first time I have run into any errors. I tried restarting it many times, but was stuck with the same blue screen. If you have any suggestions, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Distros like Ubuntu on Chromebooks generally run into issues due to how the hardware and various drivers behave. I suggest using GalliumOS, it plays very nicely with Chromebooks and shouldn't break. It also provides a Xubuntu like experience (because it's built on Xubuntu). I've seen various people have issues with booting other OSes on Chromebooks, as they're such a small community most devs aren't willing to develop fixes for them. GalliumOS is designed for Chromebooks.